# Kohana 3.1 counting ORM find_all results

Tags: kohana-3, kohana-orm

I might be searching for the wrong keywords as I find it almost impossible that I can't find this in the docs or in any forum anywhere.

from an ORM find_all() query results like

> $result =
>   ORM::factory('some_table')->where('id',
>   'IN', $ids)->find_all()

**How can I count the results returned?**

I've tried

```
$results->count()

count($results)
```

But to no avail am I getting the correct results, always a 1 in the later case since an object is returned.

Or if the count isn't possible then at least something that tells me if any results were found?

Comment: Solved: Was not assigning the $results but instead using actual ORM object, that's a no-no. The correct format is count($results)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have a typo there -- you have assigned the result to `$result`, but then try to count on `$results`.

The following code should work:

```
$result = ORM::factory('some_table')->where('id', 'IN', $ids)->find_all();
echo $result->count();
```

Comment: Actually kinda related, in fact my query spanned a few lines and I actually was not assigning ORM results to anything but in fact using the query object itself! But true, you spotted a typo in my example as well, thanks, solved.

Comment: If you are only interested in the count, you could instead of using `find_all` use the `count_all` method to get only the count.